# Duplicate installs of Node - how to remove oldest?

Tags: node.js

I wanted to update my Node version, and so I downloaded and ran the package installer from the website (OSX). I thought it would replace my old version but it seems it didn't, if I type node -v I still shows its running the old version, 5.12.0 (new installed version is 6.10.2). How would I set the new version as the default and remove the old one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to give a try to NVM.
NVM allow you to install multiple version of node.js and switch between them whethever you want.

Start uninstalling your current version of node.js. Here you can find instructions: https://gist.github.com/tonymtz/d75101d9bdf764c890ef

Then you can install NVM and the versions of node.js you want to use. Follow the install instruction here: https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Comment: Thanks, used NVM to update the old version and then manually removed the binary package installer.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to remove all the node version you have and to install `nvm` instead.

`nvm` will allow you to install/update and manage any node install.

https://github.com/creationix/nvm/